# Simplest existing tricarboxylic acid

Tags: carboxylic-acids

I am wondering what is the simplest tricarboxylic acid that can be isolated in a pure form. Would it be methanetricarboxylic acid or ethane-1,1,2-tricarboxylic acid or maybe even longer chain is required to make the compound stable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Ethane-1,1,2-tricarboxylic acid, $\ce{C5H6O6}$**, is sold by Sigma-Aldrich and has [experimentally determined properties](https://www.chemnet.com/cas/en/922-84-9/ethane-1%2C1%2C2-tricarboxylic-acid.html) including a boiling point of 278.5°C.

Honorable mention goes to aconitic acid (propene-1,2,3-tricarboxylic acid), $\ce{C6H6O6}$, which appears as a conjugate base in the biologically important [citric acid cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citric_acid_cycle). Citric acid, $\ce{C6H8O7}$ (actually its conjugate base and conjugate bases of the acids to follow), is dehydrated to give aconitic acid and then rehydrated to give isocitric acid ($\ce{C6H8O7}$, but with the alcoholic hydroxyl group on a different carbon atom), which is oxidized and decarboxylated to continue the cycle.

Comment: I have heard esters and salts of methanetricarboxylic acid but I don't think the compound itself actually exists [citation needed?].

Comment: Looking up "methane tricarboxylate" on Google -> the triethyl ester turns up. Maybe placing theee carboxyl groups around one carbon atom is possible only if none is specifically COOH, which would decarboxylate.

Comment: [This report](https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/5628561) mentions they detected methanetricarboxylic acid and that it's not available commercially. I guess it indeed decarboxylates if you'd try to make it pure, but is quite possible. Even methane*tetra*carboxylic salts exist, but I guess the thing breaks down very fast in low pH.

Comment: @Mithoron yes, I see this. As you mentioned, whether the acid can be purified (as the C5H6O6 compound is in the product quoted by Sigma-Aldruch) remains a question.